# PHP only get upcoming Sundays in a range of months

Tags: php

I have a function that gives me back all the Sundays in a range of months

```
function getSundaysForTheMonth($y, $m, $lm)
    {
        return new DatePeriod(
            new DateTime("first sunday of $y-$m"),
            DateInterval::createFromDateString('next sunday'),
            new DateTime("last day of $y-$lm 23:59:59")
        );
    }
```

Here's how I'm using this function:

```
// Get current Year and Month
    $currentYear = date('Y');
    $currentMonth = date('m');
    echo "Current Year: " . $currentYear . "\n<BR>";
    echo "Current Month: " . $currentMonth . "\n<BR>";
    $twoMonths = $currentMonth + 2; // Two months ahead

    // Get month name
    $beginMonthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $currentMonth, 10));
    $endMonthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $twoMonths, 10));

    echo "Select which Sunday(s) of the month of ". $beginMonthName . " through ".  $endMonthName ." ". $currentYear . ": \n<BR>";
    $i=0;

    // Display all Sundays for 3 months
    // Note that if going to insert these values into a database you should put them into proper ISO-8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD)
    foreach (getSundaysForTheMonth($currentYear, $currentMonth, $twoMonths) as $sunday) {
        $thisSunday = $sunday->format("m - d - Y");
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"date[]\" value=\"" . $sunday->format('Y-m-d') . "\">$thisSunday\n<BR>";
    }
```

Here's some example output:

```
04 - 05 - 2020
04 - 12 - 2020
04 - 19 - 2020
04 - 26 - 2020
05 - 03 - 2020
05 - 10 - 2020
05 - 17 - 2020
05 - 24 - 2020
05 - 31 - 2020
06 - 07 - 2020
06 - 14 - 2020
06 - 21 - 2020
06 - 28 - 2020
```

As for the day this is posted, it's `04 - 16 - 2020`. I'm trying to figure out a function to only show the upcoming Sundays. In other words, if a Sunday has already passed, it should not be displayed. So in this case, it should only show:

```
04 - 19 - 2020
04 - 26 - 2020
05 - 03 - 2020
05 - 10 - 2020
05 - 17 - 2020
05 - 24 - 2020
05 - 31 - 2020
06 - 07 - 2020
06 - 14 - 2020
06 - 21 - 2020
06 - 28 - 2020
```

Cheers.

Comment: You’re basing your calculations on a month (i.e. starting from the beginning of the current month) instead of current date. You should add a check if your result from function is more than the existing date. Alternatively you can introduce it into the function, getting the likes of (‘first Sunday yyyy-mm-dd’) (https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: @MojtabaSayari I will try that. I hope I don't get the parsing wrong. But I'm assuming it's what you typed within the code block. Thanks!

Comment: @MojtabaSayari I made the first change and it did work, but it displays the current date as the first date, which is wrong. This is maybe because I didn't make your second suggested change. I'm not sure what you mean by "first parameter of `DatePeriod` in `getSundaysForTheMonth`. Or maybe I just read the whole thing wrong.

Comment: That was my bad, I fixed it in answer. try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can check if given date is future date or past one if that was past date you can give next Sunday date as first parameter of `DatePeriod` method

```
function getSundaysForTheMonth($y, $m, $lm)
{
    return new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime("first sunday of $y-$m") <= new DateTime('today') ? new DateTime("next sunday") : new DateTime("first sunday of $y-$m"),
        DateInterval::createFromDateString('next sunday'),
        new DateTime("last day of $y-$lm 23:59:59")
    );
}
```